# JsonBackReference e JsonManagedReference, bidirecional entre duas classes

Tags: json, jackson

Eu tenho os seguintes DTOs

```
public class UserDTO {

    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference("phone")
    private UserPhoneDTO phone;

}

public class PhoneDTO {

    private String number;

    @JsonManagedReference("user")
    private UserPhoneDTO user;

}

public UserPhoneDTO {

    @JsonBackReference("user")
    private UserDTO userDTO;

    @JsonBackReference("phone")
    private PhoneDTO phoneDTO;

}
```

Estou com um problema, onde se eu converter o json para um UserDTO, o PhoneDTO que esta dentro do UserPhone fica Nullo.
Se eu converter o json para um PhoneDTO, o UserDTO que esta dentro do UserPhone fica Nullo.

Existe alguma forma que eu possa contornar esse problema?

Obs: Existe a annotation @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerator.Property Generator.class, property="id"), que resolve esse problema,porém, quando ela é utilizada, ela cria um id (o nome da propriedade que é definido no parametro), que ocasiona outros problemas quando envio duas vezes o mesmo id para o servidor. Portanto, eu descartei essa alternativa.